# Calling a Flask REST service method in different OS with curl

Tags: python, rest, curl, flask

I wrote the following POST method for my REST API, which was built using Flask. The method receives one parameter, which is a radio station url.

```
@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/predvajaj', methods=['POST'])
def create_task():
    print "Expression value: " + str(not request.json or not 'title' in request.json)
    if not request.json or not 'title' in request.json:
        abort(400)

    link=request.json['title']
    print "Link value: " + link
    cmd = "pkill sox"
    os.system(cmd)
    time.sleep(2)   
    #link = "http://www.radiostationurl.m3u"
    cmd = "sox -t mp3 " + link + " -t wav -r 22050 -c 1 - | sudo ../pifm - 90.5 &"
    os.system(cmd)
    return jsonify({'status': "ok"}), 201
```

The API runs on a Raspberry Pi with the ip address: 192.168.0.200. I tried testing the method locally (on the Pi), using the curl tool. This worked fine:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"title":"http://www.radiostationurl.m3u"}' http://192.168.0.200:5000/todo/api/v1.0/predvajaj
```

Then I tried testing testing it with a computer (running Windows) in the same LAN **with the same command and tool**, but I get the following error:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 BAD REQUEST
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 192
Server: Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/2.7.3
Date: Wed, 05 Aug 2015 11:06:05 GMT

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
```

Webserver output (two requests - one from the pi and from the other pc):

```
Expression value: False
192.168.0.200 - - [05/Aug/2015 11:05:56] "POST /todo/api/v1.0/predvajaj           HTTP/1.1" 201 -
sox WARN wav: Length in output .wav header will be wrong since can't seek to fix it

192.168.0.103 - - [05/Aug/2015 11:06:05] "POST /todo/api/v1.0/predvajaj HTTP/1.1" 400
```

So the problem is in the evaluation of the if expression. Can anybody tell me why is it failing to evaluate?

**EDIT:** Tried running curl with the `-v` switch as @meuh suggested. The content-length is different.

Pi:

```
* About to connect() to 192.168.0.200 port 5000 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.0.200...
* connected
* Connected to 192.168.0.200 (192.168.0.200) port 5000 (#0)
> POST /todo/api/v1.0/predvajaj HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
> Host: 192.168.0.200:5000
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 51
>
* upload completely sent off: 51 out of 51 bytes
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 201 CREATED
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 27
< Server: Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/2.7.3
< Date: Wed, 05 Aug 2015 13:49:01 GMT
<
{
  "status": "predvajam"
* Closing connection #0
}
```

Windows:

```
* About to connect() to 192.168.0.200 port 5000 (#0)
*   Trying 192.168.0.200...
* Connected to 192.168.0.200 (192.168.0.200) port 5000 (#0)
> POST /todo/api/v1.0/predvajaj HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.0.200:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 49
>
* upload completely sent off: 49 out of 49 bytes
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 400 BAD REQUEST
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 192
< Server: Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/2.7.3
< Date: Wed, 05 Aug 2015 13:50:51 GMT
<
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.</p>
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: Use `-v` rather than `-i` in the curl on the 2 machines so you can compare what they are each sending.

Answer (score 1):

I overlooked a note about this issue, on the [site with the tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask), which says:

*Note: if you are on Windows and use the Cygwin version of curl from bash then the above command will work just fine. However, if you are using the native version of curl from the regular command prompt there is a little dance that needs to be done to send double quotes inside the body of a request. Essentially on Windows you have to use double quotes to enclose the body of the request, and then inside it you escape a double quote by writing three of them in sequence.*

The correct command, in my case, is:

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{"""title""":"""http://www.radiostationurl.m3u"""}" http://192.168.0.200:5000/todo/api/v1.0/predvajaj
```